# How to reach API endpoint from frontend in host?

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, deployment, devops

I think I have a misunderstanding of some basic concepts when it comes to prod deployment.

I am running a backend with go in the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/api` and making the calls with a nextjs frontend in `http://localhost:3000`. During development, it all works okay in my local machine. But when I deploy it in an AWS instance (both API and frontend are run as docker images), the frontend web page calls to the API fail with Cross-Origin Request Blocked. My allowed origins in the Go route handlers are in place and in local I am able to make the cross origin requests seamlessly.

I have been trying to search for a concise answer but I wasn't able to find anything useful for me even though it sounds very basic.

I understand the request is done by the browser in the host machine, so I tried to access the IP of the ec2 machine directly, as `http://<IP-address>:8080/api`, but doesn't work either, getting the `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`.

Should I configure something in the ec2 instance or I am missing something important about cross origin here?

Comment: Have you looked at [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/cors-support.html)?